# Giving a different object name for the content of the returned list of purrr::map2()

Tags: r, object, rename, variable-assignment, purrr

I'm trying to conduct a certain a calculation using `purrr::map2()` taking two different arguments.

```r
purrr::map2(
  .x = c(1, 3),
  .y = c(10, 20),
  function(.x, .y)rnorm(1, .x, .y)
)
```

`purrr::map2()` returns a list, but I want to assign a distinct object name to each content within the list. For example, I want to name the first list `[[1]] [1] -5.962716` as `model1` and `[[2]] [1] -29.58825` as `model2`. In other words, I'd like to automate the object naming like `model* <- purrr::map2[[*]]`. Would anybody tell me a better way?

```r
> purrr::map2(
+ .x = c(1, 3),
+ .y = c(10, 20),
+ function(.x, .y)rnorm(1, .x, .y)
+ )
[[1]]
[1] -5.962716
[[2]]
[1] -29.58825
```

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425613/changing-and-assigning-new-variable-names-with-purrrmap?fbclid=IwAR3dnsbenFSibC6Upk_1rX2etU8_G-WQLIc_SmTiQpZ-J48BqmmZyVPfzOs), though note that I need the results of the calculation in separate objects for my purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the name to the result using `setNames` :

```
result <- purrr::map2(
  .x = c(1, 3),
  .y = c(10, 20),
  function(.x, .y)rnorm(1, .x, .y)
) %>%
  setNames(paste0('model', seq_along(.)))
```

Now you can access each individual objects like :

```
result$model1
#[1] 6.032297
```

---

If you want them as separate objects and not a part of a list you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! You save my day!

Comment: Is it possible to save the separate objects returned form `list2env()` as Rds or Rda files (separately)? Do you know how?

Comment: Probably something like this : `sapply(names(result), function(x) saveRDS(result[[x]], sprintf('obj_%s.rds', x)))`